# Helm upgrade not picking up changes to values done by sed command

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, sed, kubernetes-helm, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure Release pipeline that simply deploys a helm chart of a microservice to a k8s cluster. I'm trying to modify values of requests and limits by pattern matching using sed command. I've tested it locally and it works and even ran it in a bash task and `cat` the file to check before the helm upgrade task and it was done correctly.

For example if the values.yaml file has this block

```
resources: 
   limits:
     cpu: 4000m
     memory: 4000Mi
   requests:
     cpu: 2000m
     memory: 1500Mi
```

I run this:

```
sed -e '/limits:/,/requests:/ s/\(cpu: \)[^ ]*/\12000m/'     -e '/limits:/,/requests:/ s/\(memory: \)[^ ]*/\12000Mi/'     -e '/requests:/,/limits:/ {s/\(cpu: \)[^ ]*/\1900m/; s/\(memory: \)[^ ]*/\1900Mi/;}' values.yaml
```

so that it ends up like this:

```
resources: 
   limits:
     cpu: 2000m
     memory: 2000Mi
   requests:
     cpu: 900m
     memory: 900Mi
```

Thing is, after the `helm upgrade` task I try to cat the file again to find that it's not changed and the original version is still persisting. I checked the paths in all tasks and it was correct.

I tried to use multiple echo commands

```
echo -e "resources:" >> values.yaml
echo -e "  limits: \n    cpu: 2000m\n    memory: 2000Mi" >> values.yaml
echo -e "  requests: \n    cpu: 900m\n    memory: 900Mi" >> values.yaml
```

and surprisingly it works? I don't know why!

Any reason the sed command doesn't work well in Azure Release Pipelines?

Edit:
Needed to use `-i` flag and works well!

Comment: Use the `-i` flag to save the file in place.

Comment: @HatLess Totally forgot about this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there, May I knwo if the suggestion by @HatLess works for your. If yes, would you mind briefly introduce the solution in the answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlvinZhao edited the answer now!

Comment: Hi @AhmedSamir, Have you got a chance to check the answer below. It seemed the same solution that you used. If yes, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). It will benefit others with similar issues. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution along with explanation for the community

Using the  `-i`  flag with the  `sed`  command is the correct way to modify the file in place and ensure that the changes are picked up by the subsequent  `helm upgrade`  task.

The  `-i`  flag tells  `sed`  to edit the file in place, which means that the changes are made directly to the file rather than being output to the console. Without the  `-i`  flag, the changes made by  `sed`  are only output to the console and are not saved to the file.

Therefore the fix is

```
sed -i -e '/limits:/,/requests:/ s/\(cpu: \)[^ ]*/\12000m/' \
       -e '/limits:/,/requests:/ s/\(memory: \)[^ ]*/\12000Mi/' \
       -e '/requests:/,/limits:/ {s/\(cpu: \)[^ ]*/\1900m/; s/\(memory: \)[^ ]*/\1900Mi/;}' \
       values.yaml
```

Here, the `-i` flag is used to modify the `values.yaml` file in place. The `sed` command is then used to modify the `cpu` and `memory` values for the `limits` and `requests` sections of the file.